# swi-prolog で PceEmacs を使いたい

Tags: prolog

swi-prolog上で'emacs.'と打つと'ERROR: Undefined procedure: emacs/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)'と表示されます。
customizeディレクトリにあるdotswiplrcに':- set_prolog_flag(editor, pce_emacs).'を追加しましたが、PceEmacsは起動しません。どうすればPceEmacsを使うことができますか？
MasOS High Sierra 10.13.6 上で swi-prolog 7.6.4 を使用しています。

Comment: クロスポスト： https://stackoverflow.com/q/54160004/5989200 (参考：[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110))

Answer (score 1):

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=initfile

> After the system initialisation, the system consults (see [consult/1](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1)) the user's startup file. The basename of this file follows conventions of the operating system. On MS-Windows, it is the file `swipl.ini` and on Unix systems `.swiplrc`.
>
> The installation provides a file `customize/dotswiplrc` with (commented) commands that are often used to customize the behaviour of Prolog

設定ファイルの書き方を間違えているのではないかと思います。SWI-Prolog の `customize/dotswiplrc` は典型的な設定が書かれているお手本のファイルというだけであり、そのファイルが初期化に使われているわけではありません。

環境に応じて `.swiplrc` または `swipl.ini` を作成し、適切なパスに置いてください。置くパスの詳細も上のドキュメントに書かれています。macOS であれば大抵 `~/.swiplrc` を作成すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: swipl-7.6.4ディレクトリや作業ディレクトリにdotswiplrc.swiplrcという名前で設定ファイルを追加しましたがうまくいきません。設定ファイルは、サンプルファイルのset_prolog_flag(editor, pce_emacs).の行だけをコメントアウトから解除した状態で保存しています。適切なパスはどうやって見つければ良いですか？

Comment: パスについて追記しました。また、やはり設定ファイルの名前が間違っているように見えるので注意してください。`.swiplrc` は拡張子ではなく、いわゆる「ドットファイル」です。

Comment: ホームディレクトリに.swiplrcを置くことで、カスタマイズ自体はできるようになりました。しかし、PceEmacsが使えません。なぜかpicoは使えます。edit.plを見てもよくわかりません。具体的にどうすればいいですか？PceEmacsはどこにありますか？

Comment: それはPrologがどのようにインストールされたものなのか分からないとわたしには分かりません。XPCEはインストールされてあるでしょうか。